# Select duplicated field name

Tags: sql

If I have the following scenario

Table that store people

```
id_person, name, age (...)
```

And a table that stores address of people

```
id_address, id_person, city
```

If I run a query like this

```
select * from people P left join address A on P.id_person = A.id_person
```

I'm getting **id_person === null** in result set (because there IS a person, but no address has been recorded it, which is fine).

The null is comming from the table address. Is it possible to solve this without doing select field1, field2, field3 ... (lots os fields)?

Example

```
Person

id_person    Name
1            John
2            Steve  

Address

id_address    id_person     city
1             1             'AnyCity'
```

When I run a query like this

```
select * from people P left join address A on P.id_person = A.id_person
where P.name = 'Steve'
```

His id_person is returning **null**

Comment: " Is it possible to solve this", what do you mean?, what do you want to solve?, what's your expected result?

Comment: That I get the id_person (which exists in table people) and not null (because not exists in address)

Comment: @gbvisconti: so you want only persons with addresses (then use `inner join`)? Or what do you want instead of null?

Comment: you have the `id_person` already, because it exists in the `person` table, I really don't get what you want

Comment: Forget these 'astrological' queries (SELECT *). You are a developer and you should know which columns are required. List them (and if you are using table aliases or joining multiple tables refer them with a two part name `Alias.Column`).

Comment: Wait, I'm editing to place an example...

Comment: Note, there's also a syntax error, when left join an ON clause is required. (See my answer below.)

Comment: Well, you updated your question adding details that were most likely understood already, but didn't post what do you want to get as a result

Comment: In this example, I want id_person == 2 instead of null....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you only want the id_person from the people table, not from the address table (which sometimes is NULL)?

```
select p.id_person, p.name, p.age, a.id_address, a.city
from people P left join address A ON P.id_person = A.id_person
```

Comment: Exactly, picking the primary key from the left-hand table means it will never be `null` +1

Comment: Thanks for trying to help and understand the problem BEFORE act like a hater and downvote. It works now. SO is getting really bad...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to solve this without doing select field1, field2, field3 ... (lots os fields)

No - you either use * or identify the fields.  You *could* select all fields from one table and then cherry pick from the other table:

```
select P.*, A.address, A.City, ...
from people P 
left join address A where P.id_person = A.id_person
```